# Template instancing in GCC differs from Visual C++

Tags: c++, linux, windows, gcc, visual-studio-2017

I have trouble porting code that works fine on Windows in Visual Studio 2017 C++ to work on Linux with GCC 8.2.

```
#include <stdio.h>

class A
{
public:
    int value;
};

template<typename T> int GetValue(T value);

template<typename T> int GetValue(A value)
{
    return value.value;
}

template int GetValue<A>(A value);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    A valueHolder;
    valueHolder.value = 42;

    int value = GetValue(valueHolder);
    printf("hello %d!", value);

    return 0;
}
```

It compiles and runs with correct output on Windows but on Linux I get a compile error with **Undefined reference to 'int GetValue(A)'** on the GetValue use in the main function.

My real case is actually more complex with the template code being in a library that gets linked in. There I get a linking error even though I can see the instanced template function being inside the library when inspected with 'nm'.

How do I get this type of template instancing to work with GCC?

Comment: Is `template<typename T> int GetValue(A value)` meant to be a specialization of `template<typename T> int GetValue(T value);`?

Comment: Yes, The template definition "template<typename T> int GetValue(T value)" is actually an interface definition whereas the specialization is provided by other parts of the code that is more spread out. The usage scenario is that implementation can be provided and linked in as needed but the interface remains. The templated version GetValue is actually used in a templated class so the type A is not known when used there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When defining a specialization you need to remove the type parameters... change the code from

```
template<typename T> int GetValue(A value)
{
    return value.value;
}
```

to

```
template<> int GetValue(A value)
{
    return value.value;
}
```

And everything will work as expected

Comment: And note in this particular example you might as well use simple function overloading (no template at all).